# delete core data managed object with Swift 3

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, swift3, ios10

Swift 3 has migrated my code and changed:

```
 context.deleteObject(myManagedObject)
```

to

```
 context.delete(myManagedObject)
```

this is compiling fine (XCode 8b3) but at runtime complaining that the context does not have a function/selector delete(managedObject)

Here is the runtime error:

**[NSManagedObjectContext delete:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

My code is very basic:

```
func delete()
{
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate

    if let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    {
        context.delete(exerciseData)
        appDel.saveContext()
    }
}
```

Why is it no longer working?

Thanks

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Xcode 8 beta 3 - [Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8_beta_3/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_8_beta_3.pdf)

Known Issues in Xcode 8 beta 3 – Swift Compiler

> Attempting to use NSManagedObjectContext's delete(*:) method may result in calling the UIKit-added delete(*:) method on NSObject instead (part of the UIResponderStandardEditActions category) if the argument is optional (including ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional). (27206368)

**Workaround:** Manually unwrap the optional value using if let or !.

You need to check if this holds true in your case.

Comment: Good catch .... exerciseData is an optional type Exercise! I read the release notes but missed this. Thanks.  To fix I unwrapped exerciseData with: if let exerciseToBeDeleted: Exercise = exerciseData {  //delete code }

Comment: One clarification:  I had the situation where I had an optional reference to both the `NSManagedObjectContext` instance, and an `NSManagedObject` instance.  I needed to use `if let` or `!` on the *`NSManagedObject`*, not the context...