# Swift 3 Core Data Delete Object for Key

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I am working on an app written in Swift that uses Core Data. For it to work correctly, I need to delete all the objects in Core Data for a specific entity and key. I have been able to find many different questions covering deleting from core data, but as far as I can tell none of them only delete objects for a specific key.

My current code follows a similar style to the "Fetch, Delete, Repeat" method in [this article.](https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-delete-every-record-of-a-core-data-entity/) It talks about an iOS 9 updated way to do this with `NSBatchDeleteRequest`, but I have not discovered any way to make either of these only delete the values for a specific key.

Current Delete Code (I have tried to add a key to the object, but it throws an error about not being able to cast `NSCFNumber` to `NSManagedObject` at runtime)

```
getContext().delete(object.value(forKey: key) as! NSManagedObject)
```

Full Code Pertaining to Core Data

```
func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}

func coreDataReplaceValue(entity: String, key: String, value: Int) {
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)

    do {
        let searchResults = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

        for object in searchResults as! [NSManagedObject] {
            getContext().delete(object.value(forKey: key) as! NSManagedObject)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }


    let context = getContext()

    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entity, in: context)

    let accelerationLevel = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    accelerationLevel.setValue(value, forKey: key)

    do {
        try context.save()
        print("saved!")
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    } catch {

    }
}
```

Other questions I have looked at that pertain to my question, but don't include a way to add a key:

[Swift 3 Core Data Delete Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017449/swift-3-core-data-delete-object)

[delete core data managed object with Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506763/delete-core-data-managed-object-with-swift-3)

This last one looked promising at first, but the code changes it into an NSManagedObject, so I don't think it holds the solution.

[Deleting first object in Core Data (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200228/deleting-first-object-in-core-data-swift)

Thanks for any help!

Taylor

Comment: @Taylor may be you can get your solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756178/how-can-i-delete-object-from-core-data-in-swift-3/40756625#40756625

Comment: @RajJoshi It appears that only an entity is defined in the deleting data records section. I am looking for a way to delete only those with a certain key from the entity.

Comment: @KiritModi Are you suggesting inserting something instead of the index.row in order to achieve this? I don't understand what I would need to substitute it for to delete all entries of a certain key. If there is a way, I would love to know.

Comment: @Taylor we can not delete a key value from a object we can only assign nil value to a particular object's key like object.name = nil and save context value automatic delete from a object's member

Comment: If it is of type Int, would that work?

Comment: yes int assign to nil it will work