# Core Data: Exclude a NSManagedObject in fetch request in swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest

I have an entity named "Student" which stores data of students. Mobile number of students must be unique. I have validated it when we inserts a new entity of student in core data. Now facing a problem when I am trying to update existing student data it always returns the same object which is to be updated. I have NSManagedbject of a student and I want it to exclude in my fetch request.

Here is my code:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"Student")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"mobile == %@", "1234567890")
do {
     let count = try context.count(for:request)
 } catch {
       print(error.localizedDescription)
 }
```

With the above code I am always getting 1 record when updating existing student

Comment: give your core data code, may be solved your problem. or check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756178/how-can-i-delete-object-from-core-data-in-swift-3/40756625#40756625

Comment: Please include your code in the question. One can't help you without proper information

Comment: did you checked above url link

Comment: @RajJoshi Yes i checked your link but it does not solves my problem

Comment: in above code you always get single record reason being predicate with mobile == 1234567890

Comment: From your description it sounds like you're getting what you want, so it's hard to tell what problem you're trying to fix. If mobile numbers are unique, and you fetch all students with a single mobile number, then surely you expect to get a single result?

Comment: @TomHarrington I am not fetching all students with a single mobile number.   The mobile number is coming from a text field.

Comment: Yes, exactly. And so you get one result. What do you expect to happen that would be different?

Comment: @TomHarrington I wanted 0 result with that mobile number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by using NSPredicate like below:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"NOT (self IN %@)",[arrayofNSManagedObjects])


public static func checkUniqueStudent(mobile:String,student:NSManagedObject? = nil) -> Bool {

    guard let context = DBManager.shared.managedObjectContext else { return true }

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"Student")

    let titlePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "mobile == %@", mobile)

    var predicateArray:[NSPredicate] = [
        titlePredicate,
    ]

    //here I checked if we are updating an existing record
    if student != nil {
        let studentPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (self IN %@)", [student!])
        predicateArray.append(studentPredicate)
    }

    let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: predicateArray)

    request.predicate = compoundPredicate

    do {
        let count = try context.count(for: request)

        if count > 0 {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }

    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    return true
}
```