# Delete Core Data entries in multiple Entities

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

New to Swift programming and having trouble with Core Data.
I am trying to delete entries in 2 other entities that are linked to a master entity by an Int64 number.

GameInfo - Master entity. Has game number, team names, score, date attributes etc.
HomeSubstitution & AwaySubstitution - Has the two teams substitutions. Can be more than one per game. Has the game number as an attribute in each recordset.

I have made relationships to the entities and made the delete rule = Cascade.

Graph data model:
[core data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0ZNy.jpg)

I can delete delete the GameInfo recordset and it is gone, but the HomeSubstitution and AwaySubstitution records remain. When you start a new game, the old data is now linked to the new game.
i.e. Go to review the game and the substitutions from the deleted GameInfo are displayed with the new game.

Here is my code.

```
@objc lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<GameInfo> = {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<GameInfo> = GameInfo.fetchRequestGame()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "gameNumber", ascending: true)]
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    return fetchedResultsController
}()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Fetch game
        let gameRow = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        let gameNumberDelete = gameRow.gameNumber
        print("game row to delete: \(gameRow)")
        print("game number to delete: \(String(describing: gameNumberDelete))") //This works and I get the game number
        // Delete game
        gameRow.managedObjectContext?.delete(gameRow)
    }
}
```

I have tried doing a fetchedHomeController and fetchedAwayController using similar code to the fetchedResultsController referencing the different entities and NSPredicate (which works in other classes for reviewing games) but I get errors thrown.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Fetch game
        let gameRow = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        let gameNumberDelete = gameRow.gameNumber
        print("game row to delete: \(gameRow)")
        print("game number to delete: \(String(describing: gameNumberDelete))")
        // Delete game
        gameRow.managedObjectContext?.delete(gameRow)
        //Delete home substitutions
        let fetchRequestHome = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "HomeSubstitution")
        fetchRequestHome.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "homeGameLink == %i", gameNumberDelete)
        fetchRequestHome.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        print("fetchRequestHome: \(fetchRequestHome)")

        do {
            try self.fetchedHomeController.performFetch()
            let homeGameDelete = fetchedHomeController.object(at: indexPath)
            print("homeGameDelete: \(homeGameDelete)")
            homeGameDelete.managedObjectContext?.delete(homeGameDelete) //Error here to do with NSFetchedResultsController.
        } catch {
            let fetchError = error as NSError
            print("Unable to Perform Fetch Request")
            print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect that it is to do with the number of deletions is more than the number of rows I have selected and the NSFetchedResultsController won't allow it.

Edited:
Figured it all out. Used the example given in [Delete Object from Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756178/how-can-i-delete-object-from-core-data-in-swift-3) by Raj Joshi.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Fetch game
        let mocGame = getContext()
        let gameRow = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        let gameNumberDelete = gameRow.gameNumber
        print("game row to delete: \(gameRow)")
        print("game number to delete: \(String(describing: gameNumberDelete))")
        // Delete game
        gameRow.managedObjectContext?.delete(gameRow)
        do {
            try mocGame.save()
            print("saved Game Deletion!")
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        } catch {

        }
        //Delete substitutions based on gameNumber
        deleteHomeGameData(link: gameNumberDelete)
        deleteAwayGameData(link: gameNumberDelete)

    }
}

func deleteHomeGameData(link: Int64) -> Void{

    let mocHome = getContext()
    let fetchRequestHome = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "HomeSubstitution")
    fetchRequestHome.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "homeGameLink == %i", link)

    do {
        let result = try? mocHome.fetch(fetchRequestHome)
        let resultData = result as! [HomeSubstitution]

        //Loop through substitutions and delete.
        for object in resultData {
            mocHome.delete(object)
        }

        do {
            try mocHome.save()
            print("saved Home substitution deletion!")
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        } catch {

        }
    }
}

func deleteAwayGameData(link: Int64) -> Void{

    let mocAway = getContext()
    let fetchRequestAway = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "AwaySubstitution")
    fetchRequestAway.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "awayGameLink == %i", link)

    do {
        let result = try? mocAway.fetch(fetchRequestAway)
        let resultData = result as! [AwaySubstitution]

        //Loop through substitutions and delete.
        for object in resultData {
            mocAway.delete(object)
        }

        do {
            try mocAway.save()
            print("saved Away substitution deletion!")
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        } catch {

        }
    }
}

func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}
```

Comment: Your code is a little confusing without context, can you update with the entire class please?

Comment: Found the solution. Added the solution to the bottom of the post.

Comment: @GDev Congratulations on solving your problem.  But you should add an answer to your own question, rather than putting the solution within the question itself.