# iOS inserting in database

Tags: ios, swift

Hi friends I am just trying to add, update and delete data with api. But whenever I hit add data I need to store the id for deletion and updation purpose. can someone please help me with how to store id while adding in database and I can pass id to next view controller. please let me know just to store id while adding in database that's it

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var data = NSArray()
    var datasnew = NSArray()
    @IBOutlet var lastnameText: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var citytext: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var firstnametext: UITextField!

    @IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
        if firstnametext.text == ""{
            print("please enter some text")
        } else {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as! NextViewController
            vc.first = firstnametext.text!
            vc.last = lastnameText.text!
            vc.city = citytext.text!
            vc.id = ""

            let parameters: Parameters = [
                "fname":"\(firstnametext.text!)",
                "lname":"\(lastnameText.text!)",
                "city":"\(citytext.text!)"
            ]

            Alamofire.request("http://jewelish.co.in/test/insert.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
                if let JSON = response.result.value{
                    //   print("JSON: \(JSON)")

                    let dict = JSON as! NSDictionary
                    //  print("dict: \(dict)")
                }

                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            self.data.addingObjects(from: [datasnew])
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request("http://jewelish.co.in/test/get.php", method: .post).responseJSON { (response) in
            if let JSON = response.result.value{
                //   print("JSON: \(JSON)")

                let dict = JSON as! NSDictionary
                //  print(dict)
                self.data = dict.value(forKey: "Data")! as! NSArray

                let fname = self.data.value(forKey: "fname")
                //  print(fname)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello gaus, It may be solved your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756178/how-can-i-delete-object-from-core-data-in-swift-3/40756625#40756625

Comment: Thank you. I got worked with core data and I want to check for api directly add, update and delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you are waiting to navigate to the next screen until you get the response from the server. So after calling API http://jewelish.co.in/test/insert.php you might be getting some response as json or xml, for example, you are getting

```
    { fnale:"first name", 
      lname: "last name", 
      . 
      . 
      ., 
      id={generated from backend developer} 
    }
```

so try to add one more key to the response as **id** which will be generated from the backend developer. and update your `@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {}` function like below.

```
@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
    if firstnametext.text == ""{
        print("please enter some text")
    } else {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as! NextViewController
        vc.first = firstnametext.text!
        vc.last = lastnameText.text!
        vc.city = citytext.text!
        vc.id = ""

        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "fname":"\(firstnametext.text!)",
            "lname":"\(lastnameText.text!)",
            "city":"\(citytext.text!)"
        ]

        Alamofire.request("http://jewelish.co.in/test/insert.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
            if let JSON = response.result.value{
                //   print("JSON: \(JSON)")

                let dict = JSON as! NSDictionary
                vc.id = dict["id"]
                //  print("dict: \(dict)")
            }

            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        self.data.addingObjects(from: [datasnew])
    }

}
```

***NOTE:*** I have checked with your API url, and I can see the following as response, so asked your API developer to give you modified response as mention above.

```
{
status: 1,
message: "Successfully done"
}
```